# Why limit the CRC by a modulo of 24 rather than 1626?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, source, algorithm, check-sum

When looking through Monero's source code I was intrigued by the choice of the Mnemonic's 25<sup>th</sup> word which is defined as follow:

> [`words += (' ' + words_store[create_checksum_index(words_store, language->get_unique_prefix_length())]);`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/a529f0a6c9a74a4a05205c75d5b3f726e8e58ea0/src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp#L438)

Which calls:

> [`return result.checksum() % crypto::ElectrumWords::seed_length;`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/a529f0a6c9a74a4a05205c75d5b3f726e8e58ea0/src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp#L197)

In short, a modulo of 24 is applied on the CRC32 result which then represents the index of a word in the current Mnemonic Seed.

Why was the choice made to reduce CRC32's effect by applying a modulo 24 (and pick a word from the Mnemonic Seed) rather than a modulo 1626 (and pick a word from the dictionary)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no good reason. However, by chance, it just happens doing it this way makes the seed easily recordable on a cryptosteel, by writing one of the 24 first words upside down if it matches the checsum word. I don't believe that was intended though.

Comment: Which makes me wonder if using a 1626 modulo would have allowed us to detect which word is wrong based on the initial role of a CRC32.

Comment: You could do that with error correction codes, not CRCs directly.

Answer (score 1):

> Why was the choice made to reduce CRC32's effect...?

Well it doesn't actually reduce the intended effect in this use-case. It's purpose is to quickly detect if a wrong set of words was entered, nothing more.

Also, as @user36303 commented above regarding cryptosteel, a nice side effect is you can reduce the seed words from 25 to 24 words by simply writing the word that happens to also be the checksum upside-down.